Audio stops working after a few minutes: pipewire running out of buffers
I am running Ubuntu 24.04, alsa info here: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=6fb4d0bd38c61f42705e71fc7d4e7b568fda5e31
After a few minutes, applications stop playing audio. I've noticed this with VLC and Firefox.
Interestingly, even if VLC stops playing audio, Firefox will continue to work for a few minutes before also stopping all audio output.
I have Jack2 set up to use an audio interface and reaper, and I can still hear audio coming out of those. Stopping the Jack service will restore application audio.
Pipewire appears to be running out of buffers:
sam@stash-pc:~[main]$ systemctl --user status pipewire
● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-06-03 20:07:07 PDT; 52min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 13748 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 38331)
     Memory: 13.7M (peak: 15.8M)
        CPU: 22.322s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
             └─13748 /usr/bin/pipewire

Jun 03 20:59:46 stash-pc pipewire[13748]: spa.mixer-dsp: 0x5e79b037ce58: out of buffers (1)
Jun 03 20:59:46 stash-pc pipewire[13748]: spa.mixer-dsp: 0x5e79b0567158: out of buffers (1)
Jun 03 20:59:46 stash-pc pipewire[13748]: spa.mixer-dsp: 0x5e79b037ce58: out of buffers (1)
Jun 03 20:59:46 stash-pc pipewire[13748]: spa.mixer-dsp: 0x5e79b0567158: out of buffers (1)
Jun 03 20:59:46 stash-pc pipewire[13748]: spa.mixer-dsp: 0x5e79b037ce58: out of buffers (1)
Jun 03 20:59:46 stash-pc pipewire[13748]: spa.mixer-dsp: 0x5e79b0567158: out of buffers (1)
Jun 03 20:59:46 stash-pc pipewire[13748]: spa.mixer-dsp: 0x5e79b037ce58: out of buffers (1)
Jun 03 20:59:46 stash-pc pipewire[13748]: spa.mixer-dsp: 0x5e79b0567158: out of buffers (1)
Jun 03 20:59:46 stash-pc pipewire[13748]: spa.mixer-dsp: 0x5e79b037ce58: out of buffers (1)
Jun 03 20:59:46 stash-pc pipewire[13748]: spa.mixer-dsp: 0x5e79b0567158: out of buffers (1)

Is this a bug, memory leak, or a misconfiguration?
How else can I approach debugging this?
Edit/Update: The issue appears to have stopped appearing after doing a factory reset of my audio interface (Scarlett Solo 2i2 Gen3).
